# How to set up coveralls in an Angular GitHub + TravisCI project

Tags: angular, travis-ci, istanbul, karma-coverage, coveralls

In my Angular project hosted on GitHub, I'm running the tests in TravisCI using:

*package.json scripts*

```
 "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false"
```

*.travis.yml script*

```
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run test-ci
  - npm run e2e
  - npm run build
```

I would like to set up [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/), however from the official documentation and articles on the web it is not super clear what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by simply using [node-coveralls](https://github.com/nickmerwin/node-coveralls).

What I had to do was just installing it:

```
npm install coveralls --save-dev
```

And then in my `package.json` *scripts* change:

```
 "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false"
```

to:

```
 "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls"
```

Comment: this is how I have mine.

Answer (score 0):

While I do like what **@Francesco Borzi** mentioned but keeping ci in mind I think we need to do it in two steps, you don't have to publish this for a pull request unless its a success. You could fail the build

1. run the test as part of the initial step
2. publish the output from the above step to coveralls

`script:
  - ng test --watch=false
after_success:
  - cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js`